# Sentinel-1 SLC data processing in Jupyter showing horizontal lines

Tags: sentinel, sar

I'm processing Sentinel-1 SAR data and have begun by reading the data into Jupyter. Upon opening the data, I encountered the images shown below. Following this, I attempted multilooking, but horizontal lines remain visible.

Despite consulting several papers, I haven't found any guidance on this issue. Any advice or insights on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

[image]